# SharePoint Online, folders shared by external link, no sign-in - is it safe?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharing, external-sharing

If I have document library with folders inside, and share *folder1* to user1@gmail.com, *folder2* to user2@gmail.com (send link to e-mails).

As I see, user1 cannot see folder2 and vice-versa, so they see only their shared folders. But how SP does it? It saves token in browser or what..

Can I be sure that user2 will never see folder1, if he does not have link?

This is how different users see different data. Folder names are guid's in my case:

user1:
[image]

user2:
[image]

share form:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "No" (Even though you excluded the knowledge of the link for the other user)

Using the Share option without sign in is something **I would treat as unsecured data**. Anyone with access to the link can access it. The information to access the item are encoded in the link itself.

You used "never" so the answer was harsh. They will only see the folder if they know the link. Anyone with the link can access the file.

Comment: >>The information to access the item are encoded in the link itself - thank You, now I think I understand..

Comment: You can also use the "Force signin" option. That will allow the user with that email to sign in via a MS account (Which can be created on the fly, or they can link an existing one)

Comment: Dou You mean 'Require sigh-in'? I don't see force sigh-in option. Updated question with screenshot

Comment: Yes... I didn't look the exact label up. After that link is used it will tied to the account used there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that user2 will not see folder1. If User2 gets the shared link to folder1 then user2 will for sure see folder1. Only way of making it totally secure is to share the folder in question to a specific user by entering that users email.

Comment: >>If User2 gets the shared link to folder1 then user2 will for sure see folder1 - Yes, I understand it. But without direct link he does not see it, as I understand.. >>in question to a specific user by entering that users email - You mean 'Require sigh-in'? In this case user should have MS account, as I understand. External user could have no such account..